# Coded UI selecting a Check box inner

Tags: automated-testing, browser-automation, coded-ui-tests

This is my code I need to select the checkbox but couldn't select the checkbox.

```
<label class="">
    <span class="label-input">
    <div class="icheckbox" style="position: relative;">
    <input class="icheck" data-val="true" data-val-checkbox="Please confirm you have accepted Terms &amp; Conditions of Use." data-val-required="The Confirm you have accepted Terms &amp; Conditions of Use field is required." id="loginModel_IsAllCriteriaConfirm" name="loginModel.IsAllCriteriaConfirm" type="checkbox" value="true" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;"><ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0;">
        </ins>
        </div>
        <input name="loginModel.IsAllCriteriaConfirm" type="hidden" value="false"></span>
        <span class="label-text">By ticking this box you also confirm that you <br>accept the Terms &amp; Conditions of Use.
        </span>
        </label>
```

I have tried

```
AutomationService.SelectCheckbox<HtmlCheckBox>(AutomationService.PropertyType.Id, "loginModel_IsAllCriteriaConfirm", "check");
```

and

```
AutomationService.Click<HtmlCheckBox>(AutomationService.PropertyType.Id, "loginModel_IsAllCriteriaConfirm");
```

but no success. 
Can someone help me with it?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what *AutomationService.SelectCheckbox* call is in your code but I have used the following code to select a CheckBox and has always worked for me:

```
((HtmlCheckBox)object).Checked = true;
```